# Mapping UART register address to kernel for writing device drivers

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, uart

How will I map register addresses specifically UART registers to kernel for writing device drivers for UART?

I have gone through the omap-serial.c.But I did not find the mapping of the registers defined in it.

Is it different from the mapping of standalone UART driver?

Comment: What compiler and platform? (I guess TI OMAP? But be specific.) What did you try already? It's not clear if you're stuck on finding the correct addresses or the syntax for specifying them to the compiler.

Comment: yeah its for omap-4460 processor.Like in standalone UART driver we used to map the register addressess to a macro and then access it.In the same way do we have that kind of mapping in writing UART driver in Linux kernel.

Comment: *"Is it different from the mapping of standalone UART driver?"* -- Bare-metal programmers tend to consolidate the address and indirection into one macro symbol, `#define PORT_A  (*(unsigned char *)0xff00)`, so that assignment looks like a simple variable: `PORT_A = 0x12;`  The Linux kernel programming style (which you should learn, even though wallyk doesn't practice it) typically expects a port address as a numeric value without the dereferencing (in order to allow address calculations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a device driver writer, it is your job to read the hardware documentation.  The serial port documentation will specify the bits in the control and status registers and provide guidance on how to determine their addresses.  Usually that guidance is in a system integrator's document.

Let's say your research determines that the UART's registers are at 0x31080220.  Your code would then have:

```
struct resource *uart_res;  // resource handle
uint  *uart;                // pointer to actual control/status registers
uart_res = request_mem_region (0x31080220, 4*4, "my_uart");   // map 16 bytes
if (!uart_res)
{
     error ("unable to map memory region");
     return -ENOMEM;
}
uart = ioremap (0x31080220, 4*4);
if (!uart)
{
      release_mem_region (0x31080220, 4*4);
      error ("unable to map");
      return -ENOMEM;
}
```

Then you can use the uart pointer to access the registers.

```
status = ioread32 (uart + 0);   // read the status register
iowrite32 (0xf0f0, uart + 4);   // foo foo to control register
```

Give precise target information for the manufacturer, model, and options—just like an automobile—and someone will help you find the specifics.

Comment: This first part of this is not an answer; the second part should be posted as a comment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  I disagree.  The OP can answer their own question from my first paragraph.   The second paragraph is for someone to be able to do it for him.

Comment: The question isn't about the hardware, but about *how* that knowledge is encoded into a kernel driver.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  I am not sure that is what the OP asked, but I have edited in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping uart in kernel may be definded as uart device (not driver) in the some place: kernel/arch/arm/'machine'/(devices | serial or some else).

Usualy there is no neet for mapping. When uart driver probe, it connects to device and create tty character driver. To operate tty from kernel, you may add your own line discipline to tty. Then user space progam can open needed ttySX port and attach it to your line discipline. Then your code in kernel will operates communication thrue the uart port (tty->driver).

Comment: The mapping does not occur automatically.  It is either configured through a kernel configuration and build, done with devicetree (for SoC applications), or especially for non-standard uarts, a device driver is written for it.